# What is the recommended method for programmatically editing or inserting values into the field_data_* tables?

Tags: 7, entities, database, organic-groups

I'm using Drupal 7.7

I'm working on a module to programmatically add users to an Organic Group.  I'm using og_group() and og_role_grant(), but the user is not given full access without also having their group_audience field set correctly.  So, my end goal is really to do just that.  I cannot find any OG functions that will perform that function, so I'm asking, generically, if there is any Drupal-approved method of writing data into that table.

I've tried using field_bundle_settings(), but I can't get that to work, and I'm pretty sure it won't ever work.

my code is below:

```
<?php

$settings = array(
    'group_audience' => array(
    'entity_id' => $user->uid,
    'group_audience_gid' => $gid,
    'group_audience_state' => '1',
  ),
);
field_bundle_settings("user", "user", $settings);
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create users belonging to a group (able to publish content under the group, see group content), og_group() should do the trick; I'd check your implementation and make sure it's ok before going too far astray. I'm doing the exact same thing with the following code and it's correctly inserting the group_audience values into the field_data_group_audience table.

```
og_group($group_id, array('entity' => $account));
```

However, if you're totally stuck and want to try another route, you can always manually insert the data through [db_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_insert/7).

Comment: Are you trying to add users with a specific membership type to the group (like group admins)? That might be a different case, I'd be interested in hearing a little more about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm trying to add users as regular group members.  As I said, I've been able to add users to groups using og_group() and og_role_grant() functions, but these functions don't seem to be taking care of the user's group_audience attribute.  
  
What's really bothering me (and this may be unrelated) is that I can't get group members to see the body content of a group article (even if I make the member into an administrator and set the group_audience parameter manually).  


I must be missing something obvious!

Comment: Oops.  I see what I was doing wrong now.  I had enabled og_field_access.  This was giving me more granular control that I did not need.  It was restricting the fields of the node from displaying.  Turning off that module fixed my problem.  However, areynolds, your db_insert() is probably the correct answer.

Comment: Ah, I see. Glad you figured it out; these types of problems are the most frustrating ("this should work...why isn't it working?!"). Cheers!